# Dropzone.js get error on post 500 (Internal Server Error) when try to upload file more then 5mb

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

This is my code:

```
 var previewNode = $("#template");
    previewNode[0].id = "";
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parent().html();
    previewNode.remove();

    var documentsDropzone = new Dropzone("#AddDocumentModal #AddFiledropzoneForm", {        
        url: '/Admin/Admin/SaveTempFile/',                   
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        previewsContainer: "#documentpreviews",  
        clickable: "#dropzonePreviewZone",
        accept: function (file, done) {           
            $('#add-Document-submit').prop('disabled', false);
            var fileType = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();            
            var isValidFileType = fileType == 'docx' || fileType == 'doc' || fileType=='pdf';
            if (!isValidFileType) {
                $('#add-Document-submit').prop('disabled', true);
                documentsDropzone.disable();
                $('.dropzone-add-document-error-message').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#documentpreviews').show();
                done();
            }            
        }
    });
```

All is fine when I upload file that has small size. But when I try to upload file with size more then 5 mb approximately, I get such error  `500 (Internal Server Error)`. 
This is html code:

```
<div id="dropzonePreviewZone" class="dz-default dz-message default-view-dropzone-css">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open upl-img dropzone-glyphicon-upload"></span>
    <br/>
    <span class="drop-text">Drop files here or click to upload</span>
</div>

<div class="files" id="documentpreviews"></div>

<div class="dropzone-add-document-error-message">
    <div class="dropzone-error-div"><img src="@Links.Content.images.Declined_png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="dropzone-error-div dropzone-error-message"><p>Error! Files of this format are not accepted!</p></div>
    <button class="close-dropzone-error-message dropzone-error-div"><img src="~/Content/images/delete_icon.png" alt=""/>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="files" id="logopreviews">
    <div id="template" class="file-row">

        <div class="dropzone-elements-result-upload succes-dropzone-file-upload-body">
            <img src="@Links.Content.images.Approved_png" alt=""/>
            <span class="name" data-dz-name></span>
            (<span class="size" data-dz-size></span>)
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
                 aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="remove-Temp-File dropzone-elements-result-upload"><img src="~/Content/images/delete_icon.png"
                                                                              alt=""/></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me? I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If you're using asp, you need to configure maxRequestLength in server configuraiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your php.ini file, as your maximal size for files is to small. In your php ini change the value of `upload_max_filesize`. Also, change `maxRequestLength` which sometimes causes this error. I faced the same problem uploading a huge XML file

Comment: Thanks! I'm working with ASP.NET MVC. It's really help! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, it's working now! I'll mark your answer after 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of permissions.
solved by setting permissions to 775 uploads directory Then my issue was fixed.